# laravel query a collection that's been called pior

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code below to get all the rating information for a model as you can see there are quite a lot of queries going on just for the rating info can this function be done better especially for the query payload so it's not going to exhaust the server each time it asks for this information.

```
public function ratingInfo() {

    $totalCount  = $this->ratings()->count();  
    $one_star    = $this->ratings()->where('rating', '>', 0)->where('ratings', '<=', 1);
    $two_star    = $this->ratings()->where('rating', '>', 1)->where('ratings', '<=', 2);
    $three_star  = $this->ratings()->where('rating', '>', 2)->where('ratings', '<=', 3);
    $four_star   = $this->ratings()->where('rating', '>', 3)->where('ratings', '<=', 4);
    $three_star  = $this->ratings()->where('rating', '>', 4)->where('ratings', '<=', 5);

    return [
        'avgRating'   => $this->avgRating(),
        'ratingCount' => $this->ratingCount(),
        'one_star'    => ['count' => $one_star->count(),  'percent' => round(($one_star->count()   * $totalCount) / 100, 2)],
        'two_star'    => ['count' => $two_star->count(),  'percent' => round(($two_star->count()   * $totalCount) / 100, 2)],
        'three_star'  => ['count' => $two_star->count(),  'percent' => round(($three_star->count() * $totalCount) / 100, 2)], 
        'four_star'   => ['count' => $four_star->count(), 'percent' => round(($four_star->count()  * $totalCount) / 100, 2)], 
        'five_star'    => ['count' => $five_star->count(), 'percent' => round(($five_star->count()  * $totalCount) / 100, 2)], 
    ];
}
```

I was this thinking that if you just have the one query to start with like this.

```
$ratings = $this->ratings->all();
/* then use $ratings again and again how*/
$totalCount = $ratings->count();
$one_star = then query the $ratings collection here but how
```

Rating Model:

```
class Rating extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ratings';

    protected $fillable = ['rating', 'comment', 'user_id', 'rateable_id', 'rateable_type'];   

    public function rating()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    } 
}
```

This is the answer:

```
public function ratingInfo() {

    $result = [];

    $one_star = $this->ratings->filter(function ($item, $key) { 
        return $item->rating > 0 && $item->rating <= 1;
    });

    $two_star = $this->ratings->filter(function ($item, $key) { 
        return $item->rating > 1 && $item->rating <= 2;
    });

    $three_star = $this->ratings->filter(function ($item, $key) { 
        return $item->rating > 2 && $item->rating <= 3;
    });

    $four_star = $this->ratings->filter(function ($item, $key) { 
        return $item->rating > 3 && $item->rating <= 4;
    });

    $five_star = $this->ratings->filter(function ($item, $key) { 
        return $item->rating > 4 && $item->rating <= 5;
    });

    $totalCount = $this->ratings->count();  
    $avgRating = $this->avgRating(2);  
    $totalRatings = $this->ratings->sum('rating');
    //dd('sum: ' . $one_star->sum('rating') . ' count: ' . $one_star->count() . ' percent: ' . round(($one_star->sum('rating') / $this->ratings->sum('rating')) * 100, 2));

    return [
    'total_count' => $totalCount,
    'average_rating' => $avgRating,
    'total_ratings' => $totalRatings,
        'one_star' => [
            'sum' => $one_star->sum('rating'),
            'count' => $one_star->count(),
            'percent' =>  round(($one_star->sum('rating') / $totalRatings) * 100, 2)
        ],
        'two_star' => [
            'sum' => $two_star->sum('rating'),
            'count' => $two_star->count(),
            'percent' =>  round(($two_star->sum('rating') / $totalRatings) * 100, 2)
        ],
        'three_star' => [
            'sum' => $three_star->sum('rating'),
            'count' => $three_star->count(),
            'percent' =>  round(($three_star->sum('rating') / $totalRatings) * 100, 2)
        ],
        'four_star' => [
            'sum' => $four_star->sum('rating'),
            'count' => $four_star->count(),
            'percent' =>  round(($four_star->sum('rating') / $totalRatings) * 100, 2)
        ],
        'five_star' => [
            'sum' => $five_star->sum('rating'),
            'count' => $five_star->count(),
            'percent' =>  round(($five_star->sum('rating') / $totalRatings) * 100, 2)
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: I added one more possibilty, this time with just collection operations on the ratings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do one query and filter the results with php like this:

```
public function ratingInfo() {

    $all = $this->ratings()->get();
    $count = $all->count();
    $one_star = $all->filter(function ($item, $key) {
        return $item->rating === 1;
    });
    $two_star = $all->filter(function ($item, $key) {
        return $item->rating === 2;
    });
    $three_star = $all->filter(function ($item, $key) {
        return $item->rating === 3;
    });
    $four_star = $all->filter(function ($item, $key) {
        return $item->rating === 4;
    });
    $five_star = $all->filter(function ($item, $key) {
        return $item->rating === 5;
    });

    return [
        'avgRating'   => $this->avgRating(),
        'ratingCount' => $this->ratingCount(),
        'one_star'    => ['count' => $one_star->count(),  'percent' => round(($one_star->count()   * $totalCount) / 100, 2)],
        'two_star'    => ['count' => $two_star->count(),  'percent' => round(($two_star->count()   * $totalCount) / 100, 2)],
        'three_star'  => ['count' => $two_star->count(),  'percent' => round(($three_star->count() * $totalCount) / 100, 2)], 
        'four_star'   => ['count' => $four_star->count(), 'percent' => round(($four_star->count()  * $totalCount) / 100, 2)], 
        'five_star'    => ['count' => $five_star->count(), 'percent' => round(($five_star->count()  * $totalCount) / 100, 2)], 
    ];
}
```

Comment: I get this error using your example Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on array

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
$this->ratings()->selectRaw('rating, count(*) as C')
     ->groupBy('rating')
     ->orderBy('rating', 'DESC');
```

The idea is to get a count of each rating 1 - 5 on a row each with its respective count

```
$this->whereHas('ratings', function($query) {
      $query->selectRaw('rating, count(*) as C')
            ->groupBy('rating')
            ->orderBy('rating', 'DESC')
})->get();
```

Error doing this:

```
$all = $this->ratings()->get();

return $all;
```

You may be able to simplify this even further by just doing

```
$this->ratings->groupBy('rating')->each(function ($group) {
     return count($group);
});
```

Comment: I tried to do your example but I didn't mention that ratings() is a morphMany relationship. I get the following error with your code - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::ratings()

Comment: Try that instead, the polymorphic relationship should resolve now. If not try just $this->ratings->.... with no ()

Comment: Almost there but i get this error now Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DESC' in 'order clause'

Comment: forgot the column in the order by clause...  doh!

Comment: I'm getting an empty array but there is data

Comment: see what my second example does, have no idea what to expect. And try the first one again but call ->get() at the end

Comment: I'm getting this error Method addEagerConstraints does not exist.

Comment: Why am I getting an error doing that, I've edited your answer with a problem I'm having using a get calling the collection error: Method addEagerConstraints does not exist.

Comment: Thats a good question and I'm not exactly sure why... I'd like to know the answer though

Comment: If I just run that piece of code with out the get it loads

Comment: What does it return, just a query builder instance?

Comment: it returns a json collection

Comment: Sweet, does it appear accurate? Or totally not at all :P

Comment: Yeah it does appear accurate I was wondering has it got something to do with using post->load('ratingInfo')

Comment: It certainly could, having the relations loaded could make or break the query i suppose

Comment: I tried using a with statement but I still get the same problem

Comment: Is there something missing on my Rating Model that I'm suppose to have, I've updated my post with my rating model

Comment: It was missing the morphsTo method but I don't know how critical it is

Comment: Have a look at my updated question with the answer and code that works

Answer (score 0):

try to build a pivoting function with case expression to bring your results as part of one query execution that will optimize the server load much, please note that mysql doesnot have native pivoting function, that is why I recommend you using case expression, 
then you have to execute the query as a raw query using laravel query builder approach..
the following is a sample only, try to rewrite it accordingly and run it..

```
select id,
sum(case when value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) ANSWER1_COUNT,
sum(case when value = 2 then 1 else 0 end) ANSWER2_COUNT
from survey
group by answer
```